# Using useDispatch and useSelector inside a function

Tags: react-native, redux

I am trying to call dispatch from inside a non-component function that handles api calls. The structure is as follows:

```
-MainApp.js
-scripts/
--auth.js
```

Inside scripts/auth.js it looks like this:

```
export async function signIn(nav) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    try {
        ...
        dispatch(setIsAuthed(true));
    }
    ...
}
```

I call signIn() from and onPress. I am getting an invalid hook call. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> Hooks are functions that let you “hook into” React state and lifecycle
> features from function components
>
> Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions. Instead, you can:
>
> ✅ Call Hooks from React function components.
>
> ✅ Call Hooks from custom Hooks

You should import the `store` and call `store.dispatch` to dispatch an action

Answer (score 0):

The advice from Yilmaz is wrong.  **DO *NOT* DO THAT!**

You should *never* import the store directly into the rest of the codebase.  Instead, [if you really *must* access the store elsewhere, inject it from the entry point](https://redux.js.org/faq/code-structure#how-can-i-use-the-redux-store-in-non-component-files).